# My code won't update a field in a database when submitted

Tags: php, mysql

Hey my code keeps on giving me an error when trying to update it on submit

This is my code (I also have tinymce on the textarea but never had any issue with it before.)

```
<form method="post">
    <legend>Edit PClass</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descr">Description</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="6" id="descr" name="descr" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Csubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Csubmit']))
    {

        $descr = $_POST['descr'];

        $sql= "UPDATE INTO pclass(descr) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$descr)."')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        echo $sql;
        $_SESSION['message']="PClass Edited";
    }
?>
```

Comment: lose the `into` in the update statement

Comment: That is an insert syntax! not update. UPDATE table SET column = VALUE .

Comment: thank you sagi, that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [update](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) query is wrong

Your update query should be like this :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

So, update your query as below :

```
$sql= "UPDATE `pclass` set `descr`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$descr)."'";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps more like this?

```
$sql= "UPDATE `pclass` set `descr`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$descr)."'";
```

that said,you ought to use prepared statements rather than embedding variables directly into your sql.